# VS loadtest results are not written to the DB on build agent

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2013, load-testing, tfs-2015, build-agent

I created a load test repository in my local machine SQL DB using `loadtestresultsrepository.sql` script. Then changed connection string from the default SQL Server Express local db to the one I wanted to store the test results using Manage Test Controllers window. Then I ran the test using VS ,MSTest command line and Powershell locally and results were written to the DB successfully.

I wanted to achieve the same outcome on TFS 2015 build agent so that I could run the load and performance test on the CI server. When I ran the load test on CI server using a build definition that uses command line mstest task `/TestContainer:$(build.sourcesDirectory)\$(Component)\LoadTests\20_Users.loadtest`, it did not write any data to default `(localdb)\v11.0` server. But the load test ran successfully. I RDP to the build agent, open the solution from previously copied build artifacts and again set the connection string to the SQL server DB on the build agent using Manage Test Controllers window. Also created load test repository on build agent as well. But load test results are not written to the DB when I am running the tests using build definition.If I execute the same mstest command using powershell or cmd prompt on build agent, it writes the results. Can someone help me. How can I get the build definition / test controller to write the data to the DB I have configured in build agent ?

Comment: Which build are you using vnext build or xaml build?

Comment: It's s VNext build.

Comment: Does the build agent run with the same account that you use to RDP and run the test manually?